# how to add viewcontroller scroll only when it is needed? IOS/swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll

I'm working with viewcontroller and it works well with iphone5s~6.
But when I run this app using iphone4s simulator, I cannot see the bottom part because iphone4s screen is too short and I can't scroll down to see the content hidden. How can I add scroll which only appear when it is needed(iphne4s)?

Comment: Add `UIScrollView` as a subview of  your view controller root view `self.view`

Answer (score 1):

You should set a UIScrollView as an immediate subview of your viewController's view. Set the height (and width) of the UIScrollView to fill the screen, but the content view should have the height of all its contents. This way on iPhones 5 and 6 the view will remain static, but on iPhone 4S it will be scrollable.

Comment: I set scrollview as an immediate subview of the viewcontroller's view. And inside scrollview, I have my stack view which contain all content. But after I added scroll view, all contents got wider, so I can only see left part of the content and still doesn't allow vertical scroll....

Comment: @JessJ add additional constraint to the contentView - its width must be equal to the scrollView's width. This will tell the scrollView that it scrolls up and down.